# Why is there an error when I use Roblox Lua Players.LocalPlayer.Mouse:Getmouse()?

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to make a game but it heavily relies on the mouse but an error occurs saying  'attempt to index nil with 'GetMouse'' and no matter what I do it creates this error. Maybe my game is not updated (I think it is updated). I asked a similar question before but now I'm sure it is Roblox Studio's fault.

Heres the code:

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local mouse = player:GetMouse()
local Block = game.ServerStorage.Experimental

function place()
    PlacedBlock = Block:Clone()
    PlacedBlock.Parent = workspace
    PlacedBlock.Position = Mouse.Hit.p
end

Mouse.MouseButton1Click:Connect(place)
```

Comment: What kind of script is this and where is this script located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that `MouseButton1Click` isn't a valid member of `GetMouse()`. `MouseButton1Click` is used for stuff such as GUI objects. `Button1Down` is used for `GetMouse()`. Also, `.p` is deprecated, use `.Position` instead.

Secondly, you need to place your part in `ReplicatedStorage`, not `ServerStorage`. The client can not access `ServerStorage`. Make sure that you are using a `LocalScript`.

Fixed:

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local mouse = player:GetMouse()
local Block = game.ReplicatedStorage.Experimental

function place()
    PlacedBlock = Block:Clone()
    PlacedBlock.Parent = workspace
    PlacedBlock.Position = mouse.Hit.Position
end

mouse.Button1Down:Connect(place)
```

Now there's one problem with this. When you place the part, it will only show for you and it wont show for anyone else. To fix this, you will need to use *Remote Events*.